# Object-oriented Cost-calulation not working C++

Tags: c++, oop, recursion

I am currently programming a sportsmanagement software. 
You can add clubs and members into those clubs, however you can also add subclubs to clubs themselves.

Problem: If i make a new Society and add new members, the cost calculation works.

**Club 1: Member 1, Member 2, Member 3   --> cost calculation is correct**

if i now add a  second club the cost calculation for that Club is correct as well.

**Club 2: Member 5, Member 6. --> cost calculation is correct**

However if i now add Club 2 as a branch of Club 1, the calculation is still the same one as it was without the branch of Club 2

**Club 1: Member 1, Member 2, Member 3 , Club 2   -> calculation not correct.**

I would really appreciate your help. Down below is my code.

Members.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Members.h"
static int memberid = 0;


    Members::Members() 
    {
        this->name = "default"; 
        this->id = memberid++;
    }

    Members::Members(std::string name)
    {
        this -> name = name; 
        this->id = memberid++; 
    }
    Members::~Members()
    {

    }
    void Members::setname(std::string newname)
    {
        this -> name = newname;
    }
    std::string Members::getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }
    int Members::getID()
    {
        return this->id;
    }
    double Members::getIncome()
    {
        return this->income;
    }
    void Members::setIncome(double income)
    {
        this->income = income; 
    }
    double Members::getCosts()
    {
        return this->costs;
    }
    void Members::setCosts(double costs)
    {
        this->costs = costs; 
    }
    double Members::getSurplus()
    {
        return this->income - this->costs; 
    }
    std::string Members::toString()
    {
         std::string formated = " Member: " + getName() + "\n Income: " + std::to_string(getIncome()) + "\n Costs: " + std::to_string(getCosts()) + "\n Surplus: " + std::to_string(getSurplus());
         return formated;
    }
```

Society.cpp in Society.h it is class Society : public Members

```
#include "Society.h"
#include "Membertypes.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

Society::Society(std::string name, int maximalmembers)
{
     setname(name);
     setMax(maximalmembers);
     Members::setCosts(this->getCosts());
     Members::setIncome(this->getIncome());
}
double Society::getIncome()
{
    double income=0; 

    for (int i = 0, n = members.size(); i < n; i++)
    {
        income += members[i].getIncome();
    }
    return income;
}
double Society::getCosts()
{
    double costs=0; 

    for (int i = 0, n = members.size(); i < n; i++)
    {
        costs += members[i].getCosts();
    }
    return costs;
}
double Society::getSurplus()
{
    double surplus=0;

    for (int i = 0, n = members.size(); i < n; i++)
    {
        surplus += members[i].getSurplus();
    }
    return surplus;
}
void Society::addMember(Members* newMember)
{
     if ((int) members.size() < this -> maximalMembers)
     {
         this ->members.push_back(*newMember);
     }
     else
     {
         std::cout << "To many members" << std::endl;
     }
 }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: In what sense is it not working? How are you adding members? What do you expect? What do you get? Can you provided a *smaller* complete example (i.e. with a main fn) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: This is not a debugging service: what you posted is perhaps a working example, but certainly not minimal. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It is not for debugging the programm is working. However what is not working if i add a club.
Society test -> new Society ; and then add some members, the cost calculation is correct. 
however if i make a new society and then add it to the society as a subbranch, the cost only get calculated for the other members, but not for the society that was just included, resulting in a false result.
Club 1: Members: Franz, John, Mark   -> calculations are correct.
Club 2: Members: Jakob -> calculations are correct.
Club 1: Members: Franz, John, Mark , Club 2 --> calculations are not correct anymore

Comment: @MatthiasKPrime: provide [a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or no one will bother with your question. Sorry if this seems harsh, but it's just the truth

Comment: i have tried to change it to a very compact problem. Hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 0):

To an extend this is a wild stab in the dark, but you have a `std::vector<Members> members;` inside the `Society` class.

You have designed `Members` as a polymorphic class - you have virtual functions, and the various constructors set different costs etc to each type.

HOWEVER, you just *slice* these when you put them in the vector.

Your add method:

```
void Society::addMember(Members* newMember)
{
     if ((int) members.size() < this -> maximalMembers)
     {
         this ->members.push_back(*newMember);
     }
     else
     {
         std::cout << "To many members" << std::endl;
     }
 }
```

takes a pointer - which is a potential memory leak - and then treats this as a `Member`.

Consider using a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Members>>` instead.